# DataTables cannot recognize data from DOM

Tags: dom, datatables

I have this simple table and the tbody fills with loadLogsTable(); function

```
<table id="logsTable" style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
<thead>
<th style="width:9%;">Choose</th>
<th style="width:15%;">Ip</th>
<th style="width:15%;">Hostname</th>
<th style="width:50%;">Log</th>
<th style="width:15%;">Date</th>
</thead>
<tbody id="logData"></tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the loadLogsFunction:

```
function loadLogsTable()
{
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
async : true,
url: "classes/classesController.php",
data: { method: "getLogsList"},
contentType : ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
dataType : "html" ,
success : function(data){
$("#logData").html(data);
}  
});
}
```

I initialize this table with dataTables but it doesn't paginate them (i have choose 10 rows per page) and it looks like it cannot see table's data. I also cannot search in table's data.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{  
loadLogsTable();

$('#logsTable').dataTable({  // Init pagination
"aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0,1,2,3,4] } ],
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers" ,
"bLengthChange": false,
iDisplayLength": 10
});
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Hmm i cannot do this because data are in a local server without internet connection. The output of the php file is in this format if that helps
`<tr onmouseover="ChangeBackgroundColor(this)" onmouseout="RestoreBackgroundColor(this)">
<td><input type="radio" name="select_log" value="".$row['log_id'].""></td>       <td>".$row['ip']."</td>       <td>".$row['host']."</td>       <td>".$row['input']."</td>       <td>".$row['date']."</td>
</tr>"`

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with the static data then? If that works we can isolate it down to the data being appended to the dom.

Comment: Here it is but fiddle has a problem with javascript code if you press jshint http://jsfiddle.net/nr5Cw/

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1: your `iDisplayLength` is not properly enclosed by quotes.

You have: 
`iDisplayLength": 10`

but you will avoid an error if instead you have: 
`"iDisplayLength": 10`

That should eliminate your javascript errors.
http://jsfiddle.net/MmDFN/1/

Issue 2: have you examined the **ajax data source** and **server-side processing** examples on the datatables site, or looked at `mrender`? I can't say the way you are using ajax with datatables is conventional.
http://www.datatables.net/examples/
http://www.datatables.net/ref#mrender

Comment: Here is what getLogsList() function does http://pastebin.com/27RLKuzg it returns this html code and then the jQuery script adds it to <tbody>. I cannot understand why this doesn't work will the one in jsfiddle works. I don't want to do this with server side but i ll try this with ajax source.

Answer (score 0):

mg1075 is right the iDisplayLength was missing a quote.

http://jsfiddle.net/nr5Cw/2/

`"<--missing`